# Reading json file in windows 10 html5 app?

Tags: winjs, uwp

I was developing a Windows 10 app with HTML5 and Javascript.

In one part of the code I need to get data from a json file which is located in the project folder. I tried below , but it doesnt seems to be working.

```
try
{
    $.getJSON('../js/towards_beach.json', function (data)
    {
        document.getElementById("Result").innerText = "We are working on it";
    });
}
catch(err)
{
    document.getElementById("Result").innerText = err;
}
```

Does any one have a clue how I can do it?
Do I need to register this function in winjs?
[image]

Comment: I don't know the platform, but are you sure try/catch is the way to handle Ajax errors in WinJS? That seems unlikely because the Ajax call is asynchronous. Traditionally this is done using an `error` callback

Comment: i am doing all this in a js file , my question is not about the try catch statement , i was asking how to read json file . any way thanks for your help , i will think in your point of view too

Comment: This looks like it might be the way to go in WinJS? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229787.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Pekka웃 it helped me ..

Answer (score 3):

If you use **jquery** to do the request the right way is :

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "example.json", function() {
    console.log( "success" );
}).done(function() {
    console.log( "success" );
}).fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
}).always(function() {
    console.log( "complete" );
});
```

doc is here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

If you use **WinJS**.xhr

```
WinJS.xhr({url:"example.json"}).done(
    function completed(request) {
      console.log( "success" );
    }, 
    function error(request) {
      console.log( "error" );
    }, 
    function progress(request) {
      console.log( "progress" );
    });
```

doc is here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229787.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Mehdi i will try this one

Answer (score 2):

the following code will help you to read JSON file

```
var url = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("ms-appx:///data/data.json");
Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromApplicationUriAsync(url).then(function (file){

Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync(file).then(function (text) {
    var parsedObject = JSON.parse(text);
    // do something with object
   });
});
```

Put this code in a function wherever you want :) happy coding